# Using IP alias and route to visit a site through assigned IP address

Tags: linux, tcpip, route

I want to visit a site through assigned IP address.
I run the following commands:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 [ip address]
route add -host [the target host ip] dev eth0:1 gw [gateway]
```

This works fine on Ubuntu. But when I want to do the same on a Redhat AS4 server, it doesn't work. `ping` works for the new IP address, but after running route, the target site can't be visited.
    Anyone know the reason?

Comment: not programming - should be on superuser

Answer (score 6):

Last time I checked route wasn't "aware" of interface aliases. For route `eth0:1` == `eth0`.

The solution is to use the `ip route` command:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 [ip address]
ip route add [the target host ip]/32 via [gateway] dev eth0 src [ip address]
```

This command should do the trick. Make sure you're not using iptables MASQUERADE on the interface, it seems to conflict with these things.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to use wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/) and figure out, to what address the packets are being sent.